# Ошибка кода. бота дискорд на Python. Ошибка в команде выдачи мута

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делал команду для выдачи мута... Код написал, но выдается ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "<@&663790862299562054>" not found.
```

Я пытался гуглить, искать в других поисковых системах, в ютубе и других площадках. В итоге нигде нет ответа, поэтому я решился обратиться на этот сайт за помощью.

Вот сам код:

```
import discord

import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

from config import settings

import discord.ext.commands

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, time:int, reason):
    channel = bot.get_channel(752914841911558315)
    muterole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,id=664118477425999873)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Мут", color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор', value=ctx.author.mention, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель', value=member.mention, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина', value=reason, inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Время', value=time, inline=False)
    await member.add_roles(muterole)
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(muterole)

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`MemberNotFound` поднимается, если конвертер [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) [(используемый при указании в качестве типа `discord.Member`)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) не может обнаружить пользователя в кэше.

По умолчанию, библиотека кэширует пользователей в зависимости от включенных ["intents"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).

- При включённом `Presences intent` библиотека будет кэшировать пользователей [на основе статуса](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MemberCacheFlags.online): пользователи уходящие в оффлайн удаляются из кэша.
- При включёноом `Members intent` библиотека будет кэшировать пользователей на основе нахождения [на доступных серверах](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MemberCacheFlags.joined): пользователи уходящие с сервера удаляются из кэша.

Таким образом, скорее всего, вам просто нужно включить необходимые intents:

1. Убедитесь что необходимые intents включены в панели управления приложением бота в Discord:
   [image: Скриншот панели Privileged intents в разделе Bot в панели приложений Discord]
2. Укажите необходимые intents в аргументе `intents` [конструктора бота](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()  # включает все Intents, включая "привилегированные" Presence и Members
# или 
# intents = discord.Intents
# intents.presences = True  # включает "Presence intent"
# intents.members = True  # включает "Server members intent"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'], intents=intents)
```

Comment: У меня теперь жалуется на time:
Expected type 'str', got 'int' instead

Я пытался переводить ничего не выходит(